# How to make parametrized query of this

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to make this statement a parametrized query , `type_id` made me confused about how to make it.

```
string type_id="text";  
updateCommand = string.Format("UPDATE ") + type_id
    + string.Format("_Table SET Status={0},Seq={1},Cy={2},Ca={3},Iv={4}", bcr, seq, cy, ca, iv)
    + string.Format("WHERE ASDU = {0} AND IOA = {1}", station, ioa);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `'type_id'` confuses me too because it is not even valid c#. Please tell us what types your variables and columns are of and what you tried so far and what did not work.

Comment: well none of those are really sql parameters though, thats a string format that doesnt make the same results.. so, you can continue the way you have and ditch that first string format and just have 1 string format, and a bunch of parameters, or you could look at proper sql parameters

Comment: You cannot parameterize the name of a table in a query, only values.  That would still have to be build by either concatenation or formatting.  But the values in the where clause and the values you are setting can and should be parameterized.

Comment: @juharr Thanks dude .

Comment: Who downvoted ?? Why downvoting :you think this is not a smart enough question ???? Answer it if you think it's "stupid" ...

Comment: @AhmedAekbj I think the down votes are from before your edit when you had code that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @juharr What do you think about this :                             `updateCommand = string.Format("UPDATE ") + type_id + string.Format("_Table SET Status=@fl, Ov=@ov , Bl=@bl, Sb=@sb , Nt=@nt, Iv=@iv WHERE ASDU=@station AND IOA=@ioa");`

Comment: @AhmedAekbj Looks fine, I'd just simplify it to `updateCommand = string.Format("UPDATE {0}_Table SET Status=@fl, Ov=@ov , Bl=@bl, Sb=@sb , Nt=@nt, Iv=@iv WHERE ASDU=@station AND IOA=@ioa", type_id);`  Or   `updateCommand = "UPDATE " + type_id + "_Table SET Status=@fl, Ov=@ov , Bl=@bl, Sb=@sb , Nt=@nt, Iv=@iv WHERE ASDU=@station AND IOA=@ioa";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make the SQL *readable*

```
string type_id = "text";  
... 
string updateCommand = 
  $@"UPDATE {type_id}_Table
        SET Status = @prm_Status,
            Seq = @prm_Seq,
            Cy = @prm_Cy,
            Ca = @prm_Ca,
            Iv = @prm_Iv
      WHERE ASDU = @prm_ASDU AND 
            IOA = @prm_IOA";
```

Please notice, that you *can't parametrize* table's name, however C# 6.0 *string interpolation* helps out; then perform the update itself:

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn)) {
      // AddWithValue: not the best choice, 
      // but I have no idea on 'bcr', 'seq'.. 'ioa' etc. types
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Status", bcr);    
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Seq", seq);
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Cy", cy);
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Ca", ca);
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Iv", iv);
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_ASDU", station);
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_IOA", ioa);  

      q.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }
  }
```